# Bootstrap Panel align

Tags: jquery, html, alignment, panel

I have a question about Bootstrap Panel align.

I have three tables on the Website.
Left side top a *short* table (1)
Under them a short table (3) and on the right side a long table (2).

Table 2 long content moves table 3 down.

```
Current:
1 2
  2
  2
  2
3

I need:
1 2
3 2
  2
  2
```

How can i resolve the issue ?
**[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bYqJop)**

Comment: In your `codepen` you have a syntax error, replace `<class="row flex>` to `<div class="row flex">` *This is not a solution, just correction*

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYygqE

Answer (score 0):

please fix the syntax error in your codepen project and see if it resolves the issue:

```
<class="row flex>
```

change to

```
<div class="row flex">
```

Answer (score 0):

[check here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/klpWW)
check below answer once may be it is useful for you

Comment: Table 2 has dynamic content. margin-top:-128px; will not work